# Update UIButton frame dynamically during UIPanGestureRecognizer handler

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

Inside of my UIPanGestureRecognizer handler I'm trying to get my UIButton to change it's width so it's always filling in the void left by the cell being pulled left or right.

Within my `if gesture.state == .Changed` branch I'm doing the following:

```
let translation = gesture.translationInView(self)
let width = 75 + fabs(translation.x)
self.MarkAsDoneBtn.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: width, height: 75)
```

(Please excuse the magic numbers)

However the width of the button is not updating (visually), even though a `println(self.MarkAsDoneBtn.frame)` shows the width adjusting.

Is something additional required to force the button to take on the new frame size? I have tried also updating `self.MarkAsDoneBtn.bounds`, `self.MarkAsDoneBtn.layer.frame`, `self.MarkAsDoneBtn.layer.bounds` and calling...

```
self.MarkAsDoneBtn.setNeedsDisplay()
self.MarkAsDoneBtn.setNeedsLayout()
self.MarkAsDoneBtn.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

...with no luck.

In the example below, the green arrow represents the direction the user is swiping the table cell, and the red area to the right of the blue button is what I am trying to fill dynamically by altering the buttons width.

[image: Screen shot]

Stripped down overview of class:

```
import UIKit

class ChoreItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var MarkAsDoneBtn: UIButton!
    var DeleteLabel: UIButton!
    var originalCenter = CGPoint()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        panGesture.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        self.MarkAsDoneBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
        self.MarkAsDoneBtn.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.MarkAsDoneBtn.backgroundColor = ColorHelper.instance.getColor("blue")
        self.MarkAsDoneBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick"), forState: .Normal)
        self.MarkAsDoneBtn.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw

        self.addSubview(self.MarkAsDoneBtn)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.MarkAsDoneBtn.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: 75, height: 75)
    }

    func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .Began {
            self.originalCenter = center
        }

        if gesture.state == .Changed {
            let translation = gesture.translationInView(self)
            center = CGPointMake(self.originalCenter.x + translation.x, self.originalCenter.y)

            let width = 75 + fabs(translation.x)
            self.MarkAsDoneBtn.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: width, height: 75)
        }

        if gesture.state == .Ended {
            let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { self.frame = originalFrame })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `self`? It seems if the `x` value of the subview's frame is the width of its parent, the button will *start* at the rightmost edge of its parent and not be visible.

Comment: Self is a `UITableViewCell`. And that is correct, the button is initially hidden to the right of the cell so as you swipe the cell to the left, the button is revealed, however I would like to buttons right edge to always meet the edge of the table hence why I'm trying to update the width dynamically to continuously fill in the gap.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a `UIView` is moved (`frame` property adjusted in any way), it is considered to be in need of layout. So its method `layoutSubviews()` is called.

Your `ChoreItemTableViewCell` has built-in swipe recognition. It responds to the swipe by moving its entire frame relative to the `tableView`, which causes its  `layoutSubviews()` to be called. (Put a `print()` there!) This is not-so-conveniently undoing your calculations in `handlePan()`. More fundamentally, you're violating the division of labor. Your `handlePan()` should only *record* the translation state. Then `layoutSubviews()` will *use* the translation state to recalculate the subview frame.